# 403 user does not have any necessary access rights in laravel usercontroller laratrust

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get all user in my table but I get an error 403 user does not have the necessary rights. I am using laratrust and vuejs. I have already logged in as a superadministrator. This is my controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\user;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('role:user|superadministrator');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.index');
    }

    public function getusers(){
       $theUser = Auth::user();
    if ($theUser->hasRole('superadministrator')) {
     return $users;
   }
}
}
```

My api route

```
Route::get('/allusers','UserController@getusers');
```

I have tried to go through the documentation but no success.Kindly help me solve this issue

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you try this:

```
public function getusers(Request $request){
   $theUser = $request->user('api');
   if ($theUser->hasRole('superadministrator')) {
      return $users;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get app.js:302 GET http://localhost:8000/api/allusers 403 (Forbidden)